# WebPack 5 with Web worker using React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app, web-worker

How do i make web worker work with create-react-app, Typescript and Webpack 5 work? The documentation is very limited and I can't find any good explanation. I do not want to use webpack-loader etc.

I am instantiating the worker using webpack 5 suggested API. I have got it working with ComLink but it uses RPC which i do not want (further ComLink cannot copy either socket or rxjs observables data structures).

I want to create web worker so i could stream data over websockets, any pointers are much appreciated.

```
 const worker = new Worker(new URL('./test.worker.ts', import.meta.url));
 worker.postMessage("test");
```

But it throws below exception.

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:64) File was processed with
> these loaders:  *
> ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js  *
> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js You may need an additional
> loader to handle the result of these loaders. |  |
> React.useEffect(() => {
>
> > ```
> > const worker = new Worker(new URL('./test.worker.ts', import.meta.url)); |     worker.postMessage("test"); |   }, []);
> > ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current **create-react-app** is still using Webpack 4. That's why your code will not work in the current React setup.

You can eject and upgrade Webpack manually but I don't think that it would work right out of the box, as it's a major version upgrade.

I would suggest waiting until **React 18** is released, because it should include Webpack 5. Because I can see the version has been already updated in the **create-react-app** [Github repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

See [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/package.json#L73).